# I have select query issue?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have select query issue ? i can't get `SID` however i can get `WID` with the same query? `SID` is not displaying on the page but `WID` is displaying on the page

**Query For Shopping Cart ID AS sid**

```
function get_sid($id){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT shoppingcart.`id` AS sid FROM shoppingcart 
    INNER JOIN products ON shoppingcart.`pid`=products.`id` 
    WHERE products.id='$id'") or die("Shopping Card ID"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['sid'];
}
```

**Query For MyWishlist ID AS wid**

```
function get_size($id){
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT mywishlist.id AS wid FROM mywishlist 
    INNER JOIN products ON mywishlist.`pid`=products.`id` WHERE 
    products.`id`='$id'") or die("My Wish Size Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['wid'];
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich sid not displaying on the page but wid displaying on the page?

Comment: It's not the same query, what's the table structure of the tables involved? Maybe your join is failing and not returning anything? What happens when you try a left join.

Comment: The database will give you an error. This message is always a good starting point for bug tracking.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich i have tried both queries in sqlyog and sql of the phpmyadmin both queries are given me results

Comment: If the queries work fine your problem seems to be some place else. In any case you should check whether the result of mysql_fetch_array is no false. Also consider not using mysql_query and the accompanying functions at all since they are being deprecated.

Comment: Are you sure to display errors in PHP ? Try `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL |E_STRICT);`

Comment: @LaurentWartel yes i have try it and also die("Shopping Card ID"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); not working if query not working then it should be show die("Shopping Card ID"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

Comment: Echo out the query and run that in a MYSQL query window. See what error it shows.

Comment: @roger both queries are working in mysql query window . when i use product.id='11' then sid is showing on the page

Comment: @Adam Smith:Check for row count after the query and see whether the query is returning any result. Also I asked you to echo out the query so that you can see whether the id that you are sending as parameter is actually getting sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the right function? :)
Maybe the second one should be get_wid($id)?

You should get something back - try to add some logging to your function and check for the possible error code.

Check the errors:

```
if (!$result) 
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
```

and try `print_r($row);` to see if anything is fetched.

Comment: riho i replaced WID query INTO SID query then WID is displaying on the page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have no products with that id in your basket and mysql_fetch_array() is returning false?

```
SELECT shoppingcart.`id` AS sid 
FROM shoppingcart 
   INNER JOIN products 
     ON shoppingcart.`pid`=products.`id` 
WHERE products.id='$id'
```

I'm struggling to work out what utility this query provides.
Assuming the usual naming conventions, your have a 1 to many relationship between products and shoppingcarts - most people would put multiple products into one shoping cart. eaving that aside for the moment, the join is redundant since you are only filtering on a value in the shoppingcart table and only returning values from the shoppingcart table; unless your data integrity is completely broken you'll get the same result using:

```
SELECT id AS sid 
FROM shoppingcart
WHERE pid = '$id';
```

Comment: symcbean both queries are working in the mysql window or even sqlyog